# Customized date-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Picture for reference:
https://postimg.org/image/xdmqyc1kz/

I am not sure how to achieve this task. I thought about using a plugin, but couldn't find one that does what I need. So I started trying to make my own. I just can't figure out how i'm going to achieve the functionality that will be desired. Clicking on the arrow will display more options, clicking on an option will display it as selected with the blue font. It is the arrow scrolling functionality that I do not understand where to begin.

```js
$('#pay-period-date').click(function() {
  $('#pay-period-dropdown').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#pay-period-dropdown {
  display: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 301px;
  height: 208px;
}
#pay-period-date-select {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 212px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#pay-period-year-select {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  width: 77px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><span id="pay-period-date">08/28/2016 - 09/03/16</span></a>
<div id="pay-period-dropdown">
  <div id="pay-period-date-select"></div>
  <div id="pay-period-year-select"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation yet, but still wanted to so have to post it this way.*

So basically, you need a dropdown with a predefined set of dates, with a separation of 1 week, 1 day apart from each set, in the same form element?

Comment: Yes, representing pay periods. I am just having trouble coming up with a way to design this. Date pickers and other plugins exist to handle selecting dates, but they don't look sexy. So, my job is to create similar functionality, but have it look like the picture provided. I have started work on the functionality, but having trouble coming up with a reliable way to do things. Here is a fiddle of where i'm at.

https://jsfiddle.net/itsmespencer/v95webjg/12/

Comment: I understand that the arrow-down on click function doesn't work, but I just wanted to present my thought process. Also with this logic it would prove to be difficult because pay periods can extend to the past infinitely, but only 4 into the future. I wonder how I would find the last hidden element before the visible List Items to display that option.. If that makes sense, let me know.